# Install python-ldap in virtual environment on Centos

Tags: python, centos7

I managed to successfully install python-ldap with the help of other question.

```
[root@test myproj]# python test.py
[]
```

But when inside virtual environment, I get this "No module named ldap"

```
(venv)[root@test myproj]# python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ldap
ImportError: No module named ldap
```

Trying to install - I get a long error message but I think what's important is this

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.43 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o

unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Trying to install dependencies

```
(venv)[root@test socportal]# venv/bin/pip install python-dev
Downloading/unpacking python-dev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-dev
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-dev
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I've been trying to install this library for over 5 hours now, looking everywhere.
Desperately need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, it seems that the gcc compiler is not installed, but is needed to compile the python package you try to install.

Running as root (or using sudo), install it with

```
yum install gcc
```

Going further, other handy packages for development are present in the "Development Tools" group, including gcc. Running as root, (or using sudo), you can install it with :

```
 yum groupinstall “Development Tools”
```

Comment: I get message saying "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "